# Apache httpd rewrite rule for file download, the file is not named correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, download

I am using a rewrite rule in apache httpd 2.2 to download files using this URL

```
http://<MYHOSTNAME>/?crlname=CRLNAME
```

This URL should be rewritten to `http://<MYHOSTNAME>/crl/CRLNAME.crl`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} crlname=([\w\d-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /crl/%1.crl [L]
```

The problem I am encountering is that when typing `http://<MYHOSTNAME>/?crlname=CRLNAME` in a browser, the file is downloaded but the filename is wrong.
It should be CRLNAME.crl but its null.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here http://www.xoogu.com/2011/htaccess-rule-to-prompt-file-download/

A header must be used with content disposition and the filename is set in an environment variable by a second rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} crlname=([\w\d-]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /crl/%1.crl
RewriteRule ([^/]*)$ - [L,E=filename:$1]
Header onsuccess set Content-disposition "attachment; filename=%{filename}e"
```